# How to disable Hover effect on CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to disable the hover effect only when the cursor are in search position but still effect and also work on other navbar options like Home, News, Contact. See the pic.
[want to disable this hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8ovp.png)

When i chick the search field it appear a box shadow line around the search field. How can i remove the box line shadow? For better understanding see the pic.
[want to remove this box line around the search filed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AvYa.png)

**HTML, and CSS Codes**

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkslategray;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

#sty {
    border: 2px solid cadetblue;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial- 
    scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
 
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a id="nohvr" href="#">
        <label>
            <input id="sty" type="search">
        </label>Search</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** 
When i run the code, in browser it takes little space left of that navbar in browser. How to solve it? See in pic (u see a small space left in left-side beside home icon).

[image: want to remove the left side extra white space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkslategray;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#sty {
  border: 2px solid cadetblue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  outline: none;
}

#nohvr {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;">
      <a id="nohvr" href="#">
        <label>
            <input id="sty" type="search">
        </label>Search</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Hover problem solved but second problem still occurs. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer which includes fix for both issues!.

Comment: I imagine the downvote may have been for the use of `!important`, which is generally best to avoid where possible.

Comment: @DBS I understand this should be the last option, but considering the scenario I felt this can be used which is what OP needs!.

Comment: Anyway thanks for highlighting it, I have removed `Important` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Hadisurrahman, I have added fix for both incase if you want to take a look!

Comment: When i run the code, in browser it takes little space left of that navbar in browser. How to solve it?

Comment: @Hadisurrahman this is nothing to do with the code changes of this, would you mind creating another question and sharing across? I will look into it and also kindly share the code you're using and an picture of the issue for easy access.

Comment: It says that (It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 3 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments. ---Feeling harassment to see this) So that i,m unable create a new post / question next 3 days. So, i asked here.  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210374/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-hadisur-rahman).

Comment: also this (You've asked 4 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.)

Comment: @Hadisurrahman solution for your second question is answered in the chat, try and update the status.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#sty` style should add:

```
outline:none;
```

if you want to remove this box line around the search filed.

Answer (score 2):

If it is for input box:
you can use the following style.

hoever  focus are two different sudoclasses.
hoever if you mouse over the text box. when you click and start using it the sudo class focus kicks in.
focus kicks in when you start typing something in your input textbox.

Remove this from your css style

```
li a:hover {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

Add the following in your css

```
 [type="search"]:hover,[type="search"]:focus {
        background-color: cadetblue;
        outline:none;
    }
```

try this

Comment: work only for outline but hover not working with ur code. Thanks

Comment: Let me help you. give me some 10 mins

Comment: @Hadisurrahman can you try the updated code in the comment. It will help you to resolve all of your issue. There was a selector problem

Comment: Though, i got solved my problem already, rather i try ur updated code it still not working for what i want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override the hover with the same background color:

```
#nohvr:hover {
    background-color: darkslategray;
}
```